# Is there a way to pass entire object as POST parameter in Django?

Tags: jquery, python, django

Say I have a rendered template which has the object XYZ in it. Is there any way I could call jQuery.load() on this page with a reference to this object. Something like this.

```
$('#div').load('myurl.html?parent=XYZ');
```

And then be able to use XYZ as a a django object in myurl.html doing

```
{{ XYZ.name }}
```

I am currently fetching the data using a custom inclusion tag in Django because you can pass objects to those. But I want to switch to using jQuery.load() so I can refresh the DIV dynamically.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to convert the object to a string with javascript, then back to an object server-side.

Comment: javascript generally doesn't have access to session vars. It can read/set a cookie, but then we're back to it must be a string.

Comment: How would I accomplish that exactly?

Comment: .load() would require me to render a django view. As long as this object would be accessible in that view that is enough. But I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Use an ajax call then, store it temporarily, and then fetch it though an ajax call. I believe this would be the best way, assign an id to a cookie, fetch the id, make the ajax call and get the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
$('#div').load('myurl.html?parent=XYZ');
```

will have involved a Django's view and that view has to render a template with the object you're requesting.

So I recommend you use some RESTful framework like [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in order to get the [resources](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html) without having to load the entire page.

**And then be able to use XYZ as a a django object in myurl.html doing
{{ XYZ.name }}**

Well this is more complicated, since doing that requires work on the context of the template. And you already know how to do it through  `inclusion custom tags`. As far as I know there is no way of bind Javascript (client side)  with the context processor (server side).